# Align vertical text on a card with image

Tags: html, css

I need to align vertical text after image on a card design. All is fine, except the text, I need the text to align vertically because some cards have little text or a lot of text (3 or 4 lines)

```css
.cardscurso {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  max-width: 240px;
  height: 250px;
  max-height: 230px;
  min-height: 230px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 22px solid #1EA4D3;
  color: #4E4E4E;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 3.2em;
  position: relative;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.2944em;
  text-align: center !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cardscurso a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4E4E4E;
}

.cardscurso:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.cardscurso img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1EA4D3;
}

.textin {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.textin p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(20%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(20%);
  -o-transform: translateY(20%);
  transform: translateY(20%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardscurso">
  <a href="seguridad-industrial/curso-de-montacargas.html">
    <img src="imagenes/ventas/entrenamiento-para-vendedores.png" alt="Entrenamiento para vendedores" />

    <div class="textin">
      <p>Entrenamiento para vendedores</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The text is not vertically aligned, and with that code the text is align to parent, please check my code and provide me with the right code, thanks!!!

Comment: here is the cards example, the text in each card is not vertical align : https://alternika.com.mx/dazu/seguridad-industrial.html

Comment: you want the text to be centered vertically ?

Comment: Yes, after de image and blue line the text is nos centered vertically, i need that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change `<p>` tag and instead of the have to add `<span>` because `vertical-align: middle;` is not work for block element and css should be

```
.textin{
  line-height: 60px;
}
.textin span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/z306mrj4/8/
Hple this will be helpful for you